# Avoid header injection

Tags: php

I am trying to get some php code ready to submit from my contact forum. The code is working fine in generally, but the header injection part not, i.e. the form is currently not sent.

```
    <?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo "<h1>Error</h1>\n
    <p>Accessing this page directly is not allowed.</p>";
   exit;
}

$email = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $email);

$find = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:)/i";
if (preg_match($find, 'name') || preg_match($find, 'email') || preg_match($find, 'subject') || preg_match($find, 'message') || preg_match($find, 'department')) {
echo "<h1>Error</h1>\n
  <p>No meta/header injections, please.</p>";
exit;
}


if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{

$to = 'info@mysite.com'; // Replace with your email 
$subject = 'Contact Form Submission'; // Replace with your $subject
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

$createdDate =  new DateTime();
$date= $createdDate->format('d.m.Y H:m');
$IP     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$Host       = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
           'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
           'Subject: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" .
           'Department: ' . $_POST['department'] . "\n" .
           'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . "\n" . "\n" .
           'Date:  ' . $date . "\n" .
           'IP:  ' . $IP . "\n" .
           'Host:  ' . $Host;




mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
{
    mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
}
}
?>
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: can you show us your form please

Comment: a) there is no real header injection part b) $email = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $email); where have you set $email?

Comment: Based on your code, you're matching against literal strings `'name'`, `'email'` and `'subject'`. Did you mean to preg-match against `$_POST['name']` etc?

Comment: This is the part I need help for:

$email = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $email);

$find = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:)/i";
if (preg_match($find, 'name') || preg_match($find, 'email') || preg_match($find, 'subject') || preg_match($find, 'message') || preg_match($find, 'department')) {
echo "<h1>Error</h1>\n
  <p>No meta/header injections, please.</p>";
exit;
}

The rest is working fine.

Comment: @KarelKubat Yes I mean to preg-match against $_POST['name'] etc. Thanks!